# How can I calculate saturation?

Tags: networking, performance, webserver, benchmarking

I recently setup a web server on my machine. Someone told me that I should calculate saturation to see how good my server really is. Are there any scripts that let me calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to load test, [here](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html#LOAD) is a huge list of tools. Some are free, some aren't.

BTW, if this is just a personal server on your desktop machine, I wouldn't even bother doing this. Unless you are using it on a production machine, it probably isn't worth the trouble.  ;)